# Rails 4 not rendering my html event on select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried many different combinations of this:

```
    <%= f.select(:challange,options_for_select(challange, :selected => @client_intro_info.challange), {onchange: "selectedchange();"}) %>
```

But for whatever reason the event is not getting rendered in the html. The page loads fine but when I check the source the select only has a name and id attribute. If anyone knows why this event is being ignored that would be a big help. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript or a jQuery issue..

Comment: I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with

```
<%= f.select(:challange,options_for_select(challange, :selected => @client_intro_info.challange), {}, {onchange: "selectedchange();"}) %>
```

[The docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) point out that the second parameter is the `options` parameter, while what you want is an `html_options`.

Comment: I am writing pure javascript/jQuery. Is there no way to add regular event attributes to form elements?.

Comment: This is pure JS/jQuery.

Comment: Coffeescript functions are accessible by generating a global namespace: `root = exports ? this`. Attach root namespace to any function you wish to be global, e.g. `root.function_name = ->` This all reduces the pollution of the global namespace; keeping your javascript clean.